# addEventListener change not triggered the event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdown

I am having a problem, the code is working fine is JSfiddle but when relocating to actual workspace it is not working. Already put the JS library

The problem is, the listener is not triggered by the jQuery event. Here is some simple code to illustrate the issue. Notice that the problem is from addEventListener or code syntax. Any changes that I need to make from current code?

Any help is massively appreciated!.

**JS**

```js
const length_field = document.querySelector('#unitlength');

const width_field = document.querySelector('#unitwidth');

const area_field = document.querySelector('#unitarea');

const unit_field = document.querySelector('#unitmeasure');

length_field.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // using condition 
  if (this.value === "feet") {
    area_field.value = "feet";
    width_field.value = "feet";
    unit_field.value = "imperial";
  } else if (this.value === "meter") {
    area_field.value = "meter";
    width_field.value = "meter";
    unit_field.value = "metric";
  } else {
    // do nothing by default 
  }
});

width_field.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // using condition 
  if (this.value === "feet") {
    area_field.value = "feet";
    length_field.value = "feet";
    unit_field.value = "imperial";
  } else if (this.value === "meter") {
    area_field.value = "meter";
    length_field.value = "meter";
    unit_field.value = "metric";
  } else {
    // do nothing by default 
  }
});

area_field.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // using condition 
  if (this.value === "feet") {
    length_field.value = "feet";
    width_field.value = "feet";
    unit_field.value = "imperial";
  } else if (this.value === "meter") {
    length_field.value = "meter";
    width_field.value = "meter";
    unit_field.value = "metric";
  } else {
    // do nothing by default 
  }
});

unit_field.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // using condition 
  if (this.value === "feet") {
    length_field.value = "feet";
    width_field.value = "feet";
    unit_field.value = "imperial";
  } else if (this.value === "meter") {
    length_field.value = "meter";
    width_field.value = "meter";
    unit_field.value = "metric";
  } else {
    // do nothing by default 
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<label for="unitlength">Length </label>
   <select id="unitlength" name="unitlength">
     <option value="" selected="selected">--Unit--</option>
     <option value="feet">feet</option>
     <option value="meter">meter</option>
   </select>


   <label for="unitwidth">Width </label>
   <select id="unitwidth" name="unitwidth">
     <option value="" selected="selected">--Unit--</option>
     <option value="feet">feet</option>
     <option value="meter">meter</option>
   </select>


   <label for="unitarea">Area </label>
   <select id="unitarea" name="unitarea">
     <option value="" selected="selected">--Unit--</option>
     <option value="feet">sqft.</option>
     <option value="meter">m2</option>
   </select>

  
     <label for="unitmeasure"> Unit</label>
     <select class="list-dt" id="unitmeasure" name="unitmeasure">
       <option value="" selected="selected" disabled> -Unit-</option>
       <option value="imperial" disabled>imperial</option>
       <option value="metric" disabled>metric</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: any errors in the browser console? perhaps your code is running before the elements exist - a common mistake

Comment: Hi @Bravo, it display this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: exactly because of the issue I just said - your code is running before the elemetns exist - move the script to the end of the HTML

Comment: what have I need to do so that its work fine? any help is massively appreciated..

Comment: exactly as I said before - move the script to the end of the HTML - i.e. just before the close of the body tag

Comment: @Sam I ran this code and it's OK. and change event triggered when I change  the value of select box. So what is the problem?

Comment: Hi @Bravo. Thank you for your help. just put the JS script before body close tag. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code as follows:

**Note: Check the place of the javascript code.**

```
<html>

<style>

</style>

<body>
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<label for="unitlength">Length </label>
   <select id="unitlength" name="unitlength">
     <option value="" selected="selected">--Unit--</option>
     <option value="feet">feet</option>
     <option value="meter">meter</option>
   </select>


   <label for="unitwidth">Width </label>
   <select id="unitwidth" name="unitwidth">
     <option value="" selected="selected">--Unit--</option>
     <option value="feet">feet</option>
     <option value="meter">meter</option>
   </select>


   <label for="unitarea">Area </label>
   <select id="unitarea" name="unitarea">
     <option value="" selected="selected">--Unit--</option>
     <option value="feet">sqft.</option>
     <option value="meter">m2</option>
   </select>

  
     <label for="unitmeasure"> Unit</label>
     <select class="list-dt" id="unitmeasure" name="unitmeasure">
       <option value="" selected="selected" disabled> -Unit-</option>
       <option value="imperial" disabled>imperial</option>
       <option value="metric" disabled>metric</option>
     </select>

  <script>
  
  const length_field = document.querySelector('#unitlength');

const width_field = document.querySelector('#unitwidth');

const area_field = document.querySelector('#unitarea');

const unit_field = document.querySelector('#unitmeasure');

length_field.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // using condition 
  if (this.value === "feet") {
    area_field.value = "feet";
    width_field.value = "feet";
    unit_field.value = "imperial";
  } else if (this.value === "meter") {
    area_field.value = "meter";
    width_field.value = "meter";
    unit_field.value = "metric";
  } else {
    // do nothing by default 
  }
});

width_field.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // using condition 
  if (this.value === "feet") {
    area_field.value = "feet";
    length_field.value = "feet";
    unit_field.value = "imperial";
  } else if (this.value === "meter") {
    area_field.value = "meter";
    length_field.value = "meter";
    unit_field.value = "metric";
  } else {
    // do nothing by default 
  }
});

area_field.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // using condition 
  if (this.value === "feet") {
    length_field.value = "feet";
    width_field.value = "feet";
    unit_field.value = "imperial";
  } else if (this.value === "meter") {
    length_field.value = "meter";
    width_field.value = "meter";
    unit_field.value = "metric";
  } else {
    // do nothing by default 
  }
});

unit_field.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // using condition 
  if (this.value === "feet") {
    length_field.value = "feet";
    width_field.value = "feet";
    unit_field.value = "imperial";
  } else if (this.value === "meter") {
    length_field.value = "meter";
    width_field.value = "meter";
    unit_field.value = "metric";
  } else {
    // do nothing by default 
  }
});
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery why not use its API for event handling?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const length_field = $("#unitlength");
  // other variables here

  length_field.on('change', function () {});
  // other jQuery code here
});
```

You can do this with all your elements and event handlers.